# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database with some data. Now I want to update this data with Python.

This is the Python code I use:

```
print("Place your tag to activate it...")
forename = input("Forename: ")
surename = input("Surename: ")
permission= input("Permission: ")
_id = Rfid.readRfid()
cursor.execute("UPDATE rfidTage SET (forename = ?, surename = ?, permission = ? WHERE id = ?)", (str(forename), str(surename), str(permission), long(_id)))
```

The method `Rfid.readRfid()` just reads the Rfid tag and returns the id as `long`.

I tried to run the code and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "DatabaseWriter.py", line 27, in updateTag
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE rfidTage SET (forename = ?, surename = ?, permission = ? WHERE id = ?)''', (str(forename), str(surename), str(permission), long(_id)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the parentheses after your `SET` operator.
You can have more details on the following resources:

- The official query language documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html
- One of many tutorials: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/

Your query should be `UPDATE rfidTage SET forename = ?, surename = ?, permission = ? WHERE id = ?`.